# Cancel downvote bug

Tags: support, down-votes

Currently a user can downvote someone, get the badge and then cancel the downvote and their badge isn't removed. Is this on purpose or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Badges (except for tag badges) are not revoked, even if the criteria are no longer met.

Comment: except in exceptional circumstances. Badge removal does happen but it is not common.